# Can I use async/await inside an RxJs switchMap being used in an NgRx effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am setting up new Effect modules in my Angular NgRx enabled application.

When I have a view opened, I want to make quite a few requests. As there are a number of requests, I wanted to put these into their own method and have these dispatch the `success` or `failed` actions. The API for these requests are all `async` methods (they return a promise)

I have the following

```
    public viewOpened$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(myActions.viewOpened),

        // Use a switchMap to cancel any ongoing subscriptions if request new comes in
        switchMap(_ => {    
                (async () => {
                    this.logger.info('view Opened');
                    const p1 = this.request1();
                    const p2 = this.request2();

                    // await so switchMap can handle any race conditions
                    await Promise.all([p1, p2]);
                });     

            // Need to return an observable (but this is not used)
            return of({})
        })    
    ), { dispatch: false });
```

I am using a `switchMap` hoping this will look after any "race conditions" for me, i.e., if the view is quickly opened, closed, and then opened again, the switchMap will cancel any previous uncompleted requests.

But what I am finding above is the code inside the `async` is never called.

Is there a reason my `async` code is not being called and is what I am trying to do above possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wrapping the async invocation with parenthesis at this juncture you must make it an immediately invoked async function expression. Basically you're missing some parenthesis that execute the async function after wrapping the async function expression in parenthesis. I think it should be similar to:
 `(async () => {...})()`

Comment: Hi thankyou, yes this was the missing piece! I'll mark this as the answer as shows how to use the `async`, but also like the idea of just using the `forkJoin`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using promises, why not make your requests observables? The you could return`forkJoin` from the `switchMap` as follows:

```
switchMap(_ => {
    // p1 and p2 are Observables
    const p1 = …;
    const p2 = …;
    return forkJoin([p1, p2]);
})
```

Comment: Thankyou, this also works by using `from` (ie const p1 = from(this.request1()). Infact I think I will use this rather than the internal `async`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue of using the async await inside effect's switchMap.
Original code

```
someEffect$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType(actionRelatedToEffect),
      withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(e => e.portfolioDocumentDistribution)),     
      switchMap(([actionProp, state]) =>
        this.httpService.internalApiPost(
          'web api endPoint Path',
          createRequestPayload(param),
          () => call Action-1,
          undefined,
          () => call Action-2,
        )),
    )
  );
```

now createRequestPayload was converted to async-await function
so to use that method in above switchMap needed to call with await keyword
and then ide was forcing to convert entire block into async as follows

```
someEffect$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType(actionRelatedToEffect),
      withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(e => e.portfolioDocumentDistribution)),     
      switchMap(async ([actionProp, state]) =>
        this.httpService.internalApiPost(
          'web api endPoint Path',
          await createRequestPayload(actionProp, state),
          () => call Action-1(actionProp, state),
          undefined,
          () => call Action-2(actionProp, state),
        )),
    )
  );
```

but somehow IDE was again complaining with some cryptic complex error
so i solved this issue by introducing another switchMap and passed the request payload to below switchMap as follows

```
someEffect$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType(actionRelatedToEffect),
      withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(e => e.portfolioDocumentDistribution)),
      switchMap(async ([actionProp, state]) => {
        const payload = await createRequestPayload(actionProp, state);
        return {
          actionProp,
          state,
          payload
        };
      }),
      switchMap(param =>
        this.httpService.internalApiPost(
          'web api endPoint Path',
          param.payload,
          () => call Action-1(param.actionProp, param.state),
          undefined,
          () => call Action-2(param.actionProp, param.state),
        )),
    )
  );
```